# Issue with loading project into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation

I import my project `dogsRUs` into eclipse however this is my first time running eclipse on this machine, and when I originally imported it it threw up 33 errors and wouldn't even recognize `String` as a type for crying out loud. I then hovered over the error, and selected one of the two options to change it to JRE 1.7 or something, and now it still shows 33 error markers in the margin however it only gives two actual errors at the bottom of eclipse which state:

> The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
>   Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.7]' in
>   project 'DogsRUs' DogsRUs     Build path  Build Path Problem

There are errors everywhere and I know there should be none, I can't even program at the moment.

Comment: is your JRE or JDK reference properly in your build path?

Comment: seems issue with you build path. You can do following steps 1. Add jdk (not jre) in build path. 2. Clean project there is option for same

Comment: I have literally no idea what you mean by that

Comment: Okay so how do I add a JDK to the build path?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to add the JDK to your build path.

If you don't get have it you can get a version here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Then you need to tell eclipse to use your new install following a guide like 
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2011/11/15/Telling-Eclipse-to-use-the-JDK-instead-of-JRE.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project and click on `Build Path > Configure Build Path..`

On the libraries tab, make sure a jre or jdk is present. If not add one by clicking `Add Library... > JRE System Library`

Then choose one of your installed jre or jdk, if you dont have one, download from [HERE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)